# Opening Presentation with python pptx

Tags: python, powerpoint

I have got some code in python to open `.pptx`-files with LibreOffice:

```
from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation('tes.pptx')
```

If i run this code on Raspbian, I get this error message:

```
File "bukappt.pt", line 1, in <module>
 from pptx import Presentation
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pptx/_init_.py", line 15, in <module>
 from pptx.api import Presentation # noqa
File "/user/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pptx/api.py", line 14, in <module>
 from ppx.package import Package
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pptx/parts/image.py", line 13, in <module>
  import Image as PIL_Image
ImportError: No modulenamed Image
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by not having the Pillow imaging library installed. To get this to work you'll need to install Pillow. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.9.0